# imull operation on assembly ia32

Tags: assembly, x86

I want to do a imull operatation in assembly and return result to C.

The signature of my function is 'long long multiplicar(void)' and the code is:

```
multiplicar:
    movl op1, %eax
    imull op2, %eax
    adcl $0, %edx

    ret
```

My op2 is 3. When my op1 is 399 works well (gives 1197). But when my op1 is -399 i get 4294966093 and don't know why. I have to use cdc?

My op1 and op2 are long long types.
Thanks

Comment: The two/tree-operand versions of `imul` yield single-word results. You want the single-operand version implicitly multiplying with `EAX`. Also the carry flag after a multiplication indicates whether or not the result fits into 32-bits and is typically only used to detect overflow, in multi-word arithmetic the whole `EDX` register is effectively the carry-out term.

Comment: So i do not need to use adcl ?

Comment: 4294966093  = -1203, I'm not sure what you expected though

Comment: what is this format (4294966093)?

Comment: @harold: Modulo 2^32, yes, but not in 64-bits as here. In this case the single-operand `imul` does everything required, including sign-extension, and returns the result in the expected register pair as a function return value.

Comment: I do not need to use adcl and cdc because my op1 and op2 are long long correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `imul` instruction, when given 32-bit operands, performs a signed 32x32-bit multiplication. This yields a result of up to 64-bits, however in the two/three-operand forms only the least-significant word is kept with overflow indicated through carry.

Note that carry is only a single-bit flag used for error detection and cannot carry the information required to chain several extended-precision multiplications together.

In this case, after the latest edit, it seems to goal is to multiply two 64-bit variables together and grab the truncated 64-bits result. Achieving this with a 32x32=>64 bit primitive requires chaining together four multiplications by what is amounts to the grade-school method. That is `(a<<32|b) * (c<<32|d) = (a*c<<64) + (a*d<<32) + (b*c<<32) + (b*d<<0)`. The `a*c` term can be dropped here however since we only require the least-significant 64-bits of the result.

While this is straightforward in theory in practice keeping the temporaries and carries straight in assembly language is subtle and error-prone. An added wrinkle is that the operations are signed, for which my suggestion would be to build a basic unsigned multiplication primitive and adjust for the signs separately.

Thankfully the CPU *does* in fact support 64-bit multiplication natively if we instead use the 8087 floating-point unit. Note that to avoid rounding errors floating-point control word must be set to full 64-bit precision (`_controlfp(_PC_64,_MCW_PC)`) as opposed to the 53 bits which are typically used.

```
multiply: ;int64_t __cdecl multiply(int64_t lhs, int64_t rhs)
        fildq 4(%esp)
        fildq 12(%esp)
        fmul
        fistpq 4(%esp)
        movl 4(%esp),%eax
        movl 8(%esp),%edx
        ret
```

Note however that overflows requiring full 128-bit precision *not* be yield to correctly truncated 64-bits result and question does not state overflow is to be handled.